# Check if indexPath.row is row 1-10?

Tags: swift

```
if indexPath.row == 0 ... 11 {

}
```

That isn't working, it says Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to the operands of type 'Int' and 'CountableClosedRange.

(Purpose of this is to disable rows 0-12.)

What is the proper way to do this? Basic question but I don't know what to search Google for. Thanks in advance!

If I had to guess it would be:

```
for numero in 0 ... 11 {
    if indexPath.row == numero {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For check between value

Use `"~="` [range operator.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html)

And use as below

**Ex.**

```
if 0 ... 11 ~= indexPath.row  {
    print("IndexPath in between 0 to 11")
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about this operator.

Comment: This is not working, do I need to put that code in `cellForItemAt` ? every time I scroll , the tableView dequeue the cells with random backgroundColor (maybe its not working for UI, only for enable/disable? )

Answer (score 1):

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)

if (0...10).contains(indexPath.row) {
    print(indexPath.row) // 4
}
```

This checks whether the row of your `indexPath` is within the range of 0 - 10

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a range of integers against a single integer which does not work.

You need to check if the range `contains` the value

```
if (0...11).contains(indexPath.row) { ...
```

But in your case you can also simply check

```
if indexPath.row < 12
```

since the row will never be negative.